# react-navigation: calling .navigate() triggers conversion error

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When using react-navigation, attempting to call `this.props.navigation.navigate()` results in this error message. I've tried it with different components. It seems like some prop name is being passed as an object, not a string.  The navigation succeeds if I dismiss the red screen.

**Edit:** This was due to passing an `<Image>` to `title` instead of passing it to `headerTitle`.  Subtle type error.  Will increase reliance on TypeScript in the future.

[image: JSON error]

log-ios gives a bit more detail:

> Error setting property 'accessibilityLabel' of RCTView with tag #196: JSON value '{ ...

Here's my StackNavigator setup (within a TabNavigator):

```
const trackingTabWithHeader = { screen: StackNavigator(
  {
    Tracking: { screen: TrackingScreen },
    Workout: { screen: WorkoutGroupScreen },
  },
  {
    ...stackNavigatorConfig,
    initialRouteName: 'Tracking',
  },
)};
```

Using react-navigation v1.0.0-beta.11, and react native 0.47.1.

Comment: This doesn't really look like a react-navigation problem. Can you show code from the component you are triggering navigate and the component you are navigating to please.

Comment: Finally reduced to a basic case and the difference is that `navigationOptions.title` was set to an `<Image>` component.  Setting it to plain text instead (title: 'foobar') does not trigger this issue.  This makes sense if react-navigation is assuming in this case title is a string, and trying to passit as accessibilityLabel.  Logged in an issue on the react-navigation repo: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2556

Comment: added a reply to your issue.

Comment: You didn't provide enough info to answer. Read it again, which relevant parts you missed?

Comment: @Val already solved per my comment - will add that to the Q.

Comment: We need the component you are trying o navigate to this error is not with react-navigation